# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:

Tags: android

Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: to run the project due to this error . How do I go about it? Please help.

```
10-08 15:05:05.957 17562-17562/com.coretec.msacco E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.coretec.msacco, PID: 17562
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coretec.msacco-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.coretec.msacco-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5055)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4626)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4566)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coretec.msacco-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.coretec.msacco-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5040)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4626) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4566) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you using MultiDex true in build.gradle.?

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using play-services as whole in your gradle file.
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
instead use specific ones
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'

Answer (score 1):

Configure your app for multidex

1. Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

   > ```
   > android {
   >     defaultConfig {
   >         ...
   >         minSdkVersion 15 
   >         targetSdkVersion 28
   >         multiDexEnabled true
   >     }
   >     ...
   > }
   >
   > dependencies {
   >   implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
   > }
   > ```
2. Depending on whether you override the Application class, perform one of the following:

   If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   > <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >     package="com.example.myapp">
   >     <application
   >             android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
   >         ...
   >     </application>
   > </manifest>
   > ```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

> `public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }`

Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and callMultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```
> public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {   @Override 
> protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
>      super.attachBaseContext(base);
>      MultiDex.install(this);   } }
```

***Caution: Do not execute MultiDex.install() or any other code through reflection or JNI before MultiDex.install() is complete. Multidex tracing will not follow those calls, causing ClassNotFoundException or verify errors due to a bad class partition between DEX files.***

[source](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)